# Find the value of $x$ below

Tags: geometry

$AB=DC$, Find the value of $x$

[image]

I tried with Law of Sines but I get different answer every time

Comment: $<ADB = <DBC = 5x$

Comment: @mathamphetamines I got nothing

Comment: Is line segment BD a perpendicular bisector of segment AC? i.e., is angle ADB a 90 degree angle?

Comment: it must state that it is in the problem or else you can't assume it is

Comment: @mathamphetamines I don't know if it's 90 degree or not

Comment: @mathamphetamines Some one helped me, but I didn't get the answer, he said that, $ADB=8X$ so we can use Law of Sines: $BD/sin4X=AB/sin8X$ so $BD/AB=sin8X/sin4X=2sin4Xcos4X/sin4X=2cos4X$, the last part being from, the double angle formula. We also have $BD/AB=BD/CD=sin5X/sin3X$, from Law of Sines. This means $2cos4X=sin5X/sin3X$ so use angle formulas to solve this

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found, the diagram gives the equation $$2\sin(3x)\cos(4x)=\sin(5x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin(7x)-\sin(x)=\sin(5x)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\cos(6x)\sin(x)=\sin(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow\cos(6x)=\frac 12$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{18}$$